# What are the other game modes, and can they be unlocked in any other way?

Tags: super-crate-box

In the IOS version of *Super Crate Box*, what are the other game modes that can be unlocked: SFMT, and Ambush?

I'm not even close to the requirement to unlock them on any map, and I'm wondering what I'm missing out on. Are there any known shortcuts/cheats to unlock the other modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other game modes are as follows:

SFMT: Similar to the standard game mode, but more enemies spawn.

Ambush: Enemies spawn randomly around the stage.

Unfortunately, the only way to unlock them is to reach the crate requirement given to you in each stage.

Comment: Sounds like they're both harder, so guess it doesn't matter that I can't unlock them at this point. Any idea what SFMT stands for?

Comment: No idea at all.  The description is something like 'for after the kids are in bed'.